# LotusScript Call Stored Procedure Data Overflow Error

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Using Lotus Script I've declared a variable:

```
Dim SomethingId As LCField
```

I later do a

```
Set parms = New LCFieldList
Set SomethingId = parms.Append("@somethingID", LCTYPE_INT)
```

*I've also tried LCTYPE_TEXT  I read my SomethingID from LotusNotes

```
Dim intSomeID As Integer
If  doc.GetItemValue("someID")(0) = Null  Or doc.GetItemValue("someID")(0) = "" Then
    intSomeID = "0"
Else
    intSomeID = doc.GetItemValue("someID")(0)
End If

Messagebox "someID = " & intSomeID
```

my messagebox shows "someID = 0

but when I get to a line where I try to shove the data into the parameter variable I get a data overflow error.

```
SomethingId.Text = intSomeID
```

I've tried

```
SomethingId.Value = intsomeID
```

Anyone now what is causing this?  And more importantly how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the LCField documentation [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_969265LCFIELD_CLASS_METHODS_SUMMARY.html) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_969426CHAPTER_5_LCFIELD_CLASS.html)

The Text property is an array, so that is perhaps why you are getting the error. I'm assuming writing to the Text property expects an array not a single value.

However, you might alternatively use the .SetInt() method on LCField to assign your intSomeID value. For example:

```
SomethingId.SetInt(1, intSomeID)
```

Comment: If I try that I get an "Illegal use of parentheses" it doesn't seem to recognize that method.  We must be using an earlier version of the lsxlc or something... none of the code samples match are recognized as valid syntax.

Comment: What if you precede the line with "Call", for example `Call Something.Id.SetInt(1, intSomeID)`